# foundation tooltip is not working. Any idea on this subject?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

the foundation tooltip is not working . I think the script placement is wrong but i could not figure out what the actual problem is. does the tooltip has to be initialized for javascript or is it based on CSS only?

this is the script i have placed just above the closing body tag

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script>

  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
  $(document).foundation('orbit', {
    animation: 'fade'
    timer_speed: 3000,
    pause_on_hover: false,
    resume_on_mouseout: false,
    animation_speed: 300,


  });

  $(".orbit-timer").hide();
  $(".orbit-slide-number").hide();
</script>
```

i have gone through other questions realated to this but could not find the right answers !

this is the html for tooltip

```
<span data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="Tooltips are awesome, you should totally use them!">extended information</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using foundation 4 I see you have not included `custom.modernizr.js` and `foundation.tooltips.js` in you page.

**Modernizr**:

> In the head section of your page add Modernizr. Modernizr acts as a
>   shim for HTML5 elements for older browsers as well as detection for
>   mobile devices.

See: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html and http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/4jaEa/

### EDIT

Your orbit function not works because, there is a missing `,` after the `animation` option and the orbit setup must be done before the `$(document).foundation()` execution.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).foundation('orbit', {
        animation: 'fade',
        timer_speed: 3000,
        pause_on_hover: false,
        resume_on_mouseout: false,
        animation_speed: 300
    });

    $(document).foundation();

    $(".orbit-timer").hide();
    $(".orbit-slide-number").hide();

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/SdAkp/

Comment: hi works fine ! thanks, the other problem is that when i have $(document).foundation(); at the top of the $(document).foundation('orbit', {animation:'fade'}) , the fade effect does not work ! why is it so ?

Comment: I'll take a look at this other case!

Comment: There is a typo, and you must set the foundation orbit setup before foundation() see the edit.